# Is it possible to get a set of radios that will work 10 Miles in suburbs?

Tags: antenna, united-states

I don’t have much experience with radios, but I was wondering if it would possible to have two CB or GMRS radios that will connect to each other over 8-12 Miles og distance? My budget is about $175. If it helps I would know what direction the other radio would be, it’s in Lancaster PA so not a bunch of interference, and it could be outside on a deck. What would y’all recommend, and is this even a reasonable request for my budget? Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends largely on the elevation and clear line-of-sight conditions.

You will find your answer under this question

[Could I expect 12 mile range with the GXT1000VP4 radios?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/q/10485/9493)

included a simple formula so that you may arrive at a concise conclusion.